# Field Level security disable field visibility

Tags: custom-field, permissions, profile, field-level-security

On Opportunity are two Custom Fields Product__c  (controlling field) and Product_Type__c (Dependent Field)

When i check the field level security on these fields, it is visible for all Profiles. I want these fields to be not visible for ll profiles. However I am unable to edit the Field level Security.

[image]

Also, from Set up > Profile > Object Settings > Edit > 'search the custom objects', the checkboxes next to these two fields are greyed out. I do not want to assign these two fields to the profile.
[image]

I am wondering how can i edit the Field Level Security and revoke the permissions to these fields for the profile?

Comment: Are those fields marked as required on the object?

Comment: yes Mark, they were. I made them Not required on the Object, and required on Page Layout. Now I am able to edit the visibility.

Comment: Excellent. You should add an official answer here, to yourself, and accept it... so that someone who comes along later can see your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @MarkPond in pointing me in the correct direction. I was able to resolve this.

**Steps to resolve**

1. Setup > Object > Fields
2. Set Field Level Security
3. Make the field **not** required
4. Set Up >  Profile > Object Settings > "Now the field is available for editing"
5. Made the field required on Pagelayout